# If $\mathbb E[\sup_{t\in [0,T]}|X_t|]<\infty$, is $(X_t)_{t\in [0,T]}$ uniformly integrable?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, martingales, uniform-integrability

Let $(X_t)_{t\in [0,T]}$ a stochastic process. If $$\mathbb E\left[\sup_{t\in [0,T]}|X_t|\right]<\infty \,,$$ is $(X_t)_{t\in [0,T]}$ uniformly integrable ?

For me it's uniformly integrable if and only if $$\lim_{M\to \infty }\sup_{t\in [0,T]}\int_{|X_t|\geq M}|X_t|d\mathbb P=0.$$

I'm rather sure that it's not true since if $(X_t)$ is a continuous submartingal, we have that $$\mathbb E[\sup_{t\in [0,T]} |X_t|^p]\leq C\sup_{t\in [0,T]}\mathbb E[|X_t|],$$
so uniformly integrable would implies $\mathbb E[\sup_t |X_t|]<\infty $. But I can't find an example where the converse doesn't hold. Any idea ?

Comment: I don't think this is true, yet I don't know an immediate counterexample.

Comment: If $S := \sup \limits_{t \in [0,T]} |X_t|$ and your assumption is that $S \in L^1$, then for every $t \in [0,T]$ we have $|X_t| \leq S$. Does this not imply $\{X_t\}_{t \in [0,T]}$ is uniformly integrable?

Comment: Since for every $t$, $\mathbb{E}[|X_t| 1_{|X_t| \geq M}|] \leq \mathbb{E}[S 1_{S\geq M}]$.

Answer (score 3):

The statement holds, consider the process $Y_n:= \sup_{t \in [0,T] } \mathbb{1}_{|X_t|\geq n}|X_t|$. This process is dominated by the integrable rv $\sup _{[0,T]}|X_t|$ and is monotone decreasing, therefore we have by monotone convergence $\lim _{n \to \infty}\mathbb{E}[Y_n] = \mathbb{E} [\lim _{n \to \infty} \sup _{t \in [0,T]}Y_n ]=\mathbb{E}[0]$ because $ \mathbb{P} (\exists_{t_m \in [0,T]} \lim _{m \to \infty}|X_{t_m}| = \infty) = 0 $ and this is the only set where $\lim _{n \to \infty} \sup _{t \in [0,T]}Y_n $ does not converge to zero. We now see that $\sup _{t \in [0,T]} \mathbb{E} [\mathbb{1}_{|X_t| \geq n} |X_t|] $ is dominated by $\mathbb{E} [Y_n]$ and therefore also converges to 0.